# SELECT SUM () by DISTINCT intervals (Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose we have a table:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name   Date                   Value ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════╣
║ John   2013-01-01 10:20:00    10    ║
║ John   2013-01-01 12:20:11    20    ║
║ Mark   2013-01-01 11:44:10    10    ║
║ Mark   2013-01-02 12:00:00    20    ║
║ Mark   2013-01-03 15:20:00    20    ║
║ Tim    2013-01-01 15:11:12    5     ║
║ Tim    2013-01-03 18:44:44    10    ║
║ Tim    2013-01-03 20:11:00    15    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════╝
```

And using a single `SELECT` query, output:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name    2013-01-01    2013-01-02    2013-01-03 ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ John    30            0             0          ║
║ Mark    10            20            20         ║
║ Tim     5             0             25         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- The 3 days are fixed (2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 2013-01-02).

How do you do this in a single `SELECT`? I tried with `SUM(DISTINCT)` but no success. I cannot figure out the logic.

It must be `GROUP BY Name` only (I think), but how would I compute the `SUM()` by intervals?

Comment: you may want to look at using a pivot query: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CAST(DATE AS DATE) = '2013-01-01' THEN VALUE 
             ELSE 0 
           END) [2013-01-01], 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CAST(DATE AS DATE) = '2013-01-02' THEN VALUE 
             ELSE 0 
           END) [2013-01-02], 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CAST(DATE AS DATE) = '2013-01-03' THEN VALUE 
             ELSE 0 
           END) [2013-01-03] 
FROM   TABLE1 
GROUP  BY NAME
```

Take a look at the working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/805fb/5).

Comment: great ... i did'n know that you can put `case when` in the `SUM()` function .. brilliant ... but what is the logic in SQL ? How does it interpret this ... ?

Comment: What do you mean with "what is the logic in SQL"?

Comment: how sql compute this ... it group by name and then the sum function is applied ... what happend in the SUM function ?

Comment: OK, now I understand the question. Think of it this way, the sum normally takes the values of all the rows and adds them up. Using the CASE we replace some of the values (those not from the correct date) with the 0 value (in other words, skipping these values).
The Sum then sums the remaining values and groups them by NAME.

I hope this was clear enough :-)

Comment: so the sql interpreter firsts run the select case ... then apply sum() on the resulting fields .. right ? like this select a.name, sum(a.[2013-01-01], .... from (select name, case when ....)

Answer (score 3):

If the dates are fixed:

```
SELECT  [Name],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= '20130101' 
            AND [Date] < '20130102' THEN Value END) [2013-01-01],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= '20130102' 
            AND [Date] < '20130103' THEN Value END) [2013-01-02],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= '20130103' 
            AND [Date] < '20130104' THEN Value END) [2013-01-03]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME, 
    ISNULL([2013-01-01],0) [2013-01-01], 
    ISNULL([2013-01-02],0) [2013-01-02], 
    ISNULL([2013-01-03],0) [2013-01-03]
FROM (
    SELECT NAME, CONVERT(DATE, [Date]) [Date], SUM([Value]) [Value]
    FROM   TABLE1
    GROUP  BY NAME, CONVERT(DATE, [Date])
  ) src
PIVOT (
   SUM([Value])
   FOR [Date]
   IN ( [2013-01-01], [2013-01-02], [2013-01-03])
  ) pvt
```

The date columns may have to be specified differently, depending on how they would print out.

[SQL Authority Pivot Example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/)
[My SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92b75/10)

Comment: The incorrect value "2013-01-01" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: @123onetwothree i've updated my example and provided an sql fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
                     SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(DATE as DATE))
                     FROM (
                           SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATE as DATE) DATE FROM #YourTable
                           ) tbl
                     ORDER BY DATE
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                           ,TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 
       'WITH CTE (
    NAME
    ,DATE
    ,VALUE
    )
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,CAST(DATE AS DATE)
        ,Cast(Value AS INT)
    FROM #YourTable
    )
SELECT NAME
    ,' + @cols + '
FROM CTE
PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR DATE IN (' + @cols + ')) PVT;'

EXECUTE (@query);
```